# How to find all classes that get called once main() is triggered?

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to find every class that touches the `main()` in a project I have. We use both `Java` and `Groovy` with `gradle`. This project includes many different jars that get compiled, with many different `main()` methods. We are trying to tear apart this massive project and move them all into separate `git` repositories. Currently we use `SVN` with the Eclipse IDE and are moving to `git` and IntelliJ.

How do I find every single class that interacts with my `main()` method so that I can copy/extract/cut them all out at once, or in a similar fashion? That and ONLY classes that touch this `main()` class. We want to remove just this one project from this massive group of projects.

Example:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
  AClass.init();
  BClass.init();
  CClass.init();
  DClass.init();
}
...
public class AClass {
  //calls a number of classes
}
...
public class ABlass {
  //calls 15 other classes
}
...etc
```

I want to know every class that `main()` calls, `AClass` calls, `BClass` calls, the classes that call other classes within all other classes that are tied to `main()`. Is this possible? I can use either `Eclipse` or `IntelliJ` to help me search for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just about impossible to get it perfect because of reflection. More classes can get loaded as your app runs. But you could try adding `-verbose:class` to your launch command and sending that to a file and parsing the result. That will list all the classes that get loaded.

You would add `-verbos:class` to wherever you run your application. The screenshot below is in IntelliJ but you could do the same thing wherever you're running your `java` command. Command line or IDE.

That will give you output like this (a lot of it). Which will be a lot more than you'll probably want but you could parse it to find what you're looking for based on packages.

```
[Loaded java.io.StreamCorruptedException from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded org.entando.entando.aps.system.init.model.AbstractReport from file:/projects/entando/entando-core/engine/target/classes/]
[Loaded org.entando.entando.aps.system.init.model.DataSourceInstallationReport from file:/projects/entando/entando-core/engine/target/classes/]
[Loaded org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToEnumConverterFactory$StringToEnum from file:/Users/josephwhite/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.8.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar]
[Loaded org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils$$Lambda$69/2073333566 from org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils]
[Loaded org.springframework.core.NestedExceptionUtils from file:/Users/josephwhite/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.8.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar]
[Loaded org.entando.entando.aps.system.init.model.InvalidPostProcessResultException from file:/projects/entando/entando-core/engine/target/classes/]
[Loaded org.entando.entando.aps.system.init.model.IPostProcess from file:/projects/entando/entando-core/engine/target/classes/]
[Loaded org.entando.entando.aps.system.init.model.SelfRestCallPostProcess from file:/projects/entando/entando-core/engine/target/classes/]
[Loaded javax.ws.rs.core.Response$StatusType from file:/Users/josephwhite/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0.1/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar]
[Loaded javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status from file:/Users/josephwhite/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0.1/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar]
[Loaded org.entando.entando.aps.system.services.api.model.ApiMethod from file:/projects/entando/entando-core/engine/target/classes/]
[Loaded org.entando.entando.aps.system.init.cache.IInitializerManagerCacheWrapper from file:/projects/entando/entando-core/engine/target/classes/]
[Loaded org.entando.entando.aps.system.init.model.SystemInstallationReport$Status from file:/projects/entando/entando-core/engine/target/classes/]
[Loaded com.agiletec.aps.system.common.AbstractCacheWrapper from file:/projects/entando/entando-core/engine/target/classes/]
[Loaded org.entando.entando.aps.system.init.cache.InitializerManagerCacheWrapper from file:/projects/entando/entando-core/engine/target/classes/]
```

However, you might think carefully about your approach here. It may be better to create your new project, move the first few classes over, and then fix compilation errors as you go. You'll get a better view into how things are wired together and even if it is many hundreds of classes it might be worth it.

Here is an example in IntelliJ[image]

Comment: Could you comment an example command of how that would look like? The unfortunate thing is based on different criteria, the app runs different ways. I may have to run this multiple times.

Comment: @SovietFrontier added details. You would pass that argument wherever you're running your app.